# Empty EditText when turning screen on and Screen lock set to None

Tags: android

I'm having a problem where an EditText in landscape/full screen mode becomes empty after turning the screen off and then on when the system Screen lock is set to None.  The keyboard remains active, but it doesn't appear to have focus and no text updates are displayed on the screen.  If I tap the Done button or rotate to portrait, then the full screen editor is removed and I can see the previously entered text in the normal EditText view.

I'm reproducing this on JB in both the emulator and a device.  The EditText has an android:id and I've found this problem with a variety of EditText and AutoCompleteTextView configurations, but only when the system Screen lock setting is set to None.  Everything works fine when it's set to Slide or Pattern, so I suspect that the lack of a screen lock is the source of this problem.

I found the same problem in Calendar, but not in Messaging.  When editing an SMS message in landscape/full screen mode and then turning the screen off/on, at first the message appears to be empty, but then it returns after a second.  I reviewed the source code below, but I didn't see anything special in onResume() that appeared to be addressing this issue.

https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms/blob/master/src/com/android/mms/ui/ComposeMessageActivity.java

Does anyone know how to properly fix this, so that when Screen lock is None you can edit text in landscape/full screen mode, turn the screen off and then back on, and the text is displayed just as you left it?

Comment: mean when you change your device portrait to landscape it will remove your data is it ?

Comment: No, orientation changes work fine.  It's about being in the full screen landscape editor, turning the screen off and then on, and the text is no longer displayed in the editor.  This is only a problem when the system Screen lock is set to None.  When it's any other value, such as Slider or Pattern, the text is properly displayed in the editor after turning the screen on and unlocking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a (hopefully) temporary fix, I have included the following line in `onResume()` and it appears to do the trick.  Initially I tried to only run this when the IME `isFullscreenMode()`, but this returns false in `onResume()` (after returning true in `onPause()`).  I would guess that this is part of the root of the problem.  When system Screen lock is None and the screen is turned on, the IME doesn't know that it's in full screen mode when it actually is.

```
View view = getCurrentFocus();

if (view != null) {
    ((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
            .restartInput(view);
}
```